# WCF and streaming large data

Tags: performance, wcf, streaming

I'm working with large data in wcf (gigs).  I need to return this to the client and the previous code wrote a memory stream and then returned this to the client as a property on a streamed data contract.

The problem is that the data has grown and the memory stream now uses all available memory and eventually fails before all the data is written to the stream.

Is it possible to write the data to the stream on-demand, so the server is writing it was the client is requesting it?

Comment: show us what you have tried yet

Answer (score 0):

Here's our code;

```
internal  StreamedFileResponse CreateStream()
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var writer = new CsvWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(rowFactory.CreateHeader());

        foreach (var source in sources)
        {
            var row = rowFactory.Create(source);
            if (row != null)
            {
                writer.Write(row);
            }
        }
    }

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return new StreamedFileResponse { Data = stream, Length = stream.Length };
}

[MessageContract(WrapperNamespace = "http://www.contoso.com/services/contract/reports/streamed")]
public class StreamedFileResponse : IDisposable
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream Data { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long Length { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Data.Dispose();
    }       
}
```